# train custom plate recognition using yolo

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo, yolov5

I want to train my custom license plate using Yolov5, but I have a problem.

My problem is that my dataset is separated for each character and I have no idea how to make  annotation file suitable for Yolo which is as follows.

Because what I've seen so far, for training, you definitely need the entire license plate, which can be used to label each of the characters.

If I train these images, can I achieve a license plate recognition system?

Answer (score 0):

With Yolov5, you can achieve a good licence plate detection system, Yolov5 wont be reach the succes to recognite the licence plates itself. After the detection(with Yolov5) you can extract the information from bounding boxes and use it for recognition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).